# "EQP" on air ticket confirmation via a travel agency

Tags: air-travel, bookings, travel-agents

I recently booked a flight through a travel agency and I found this section in my booking confirmation they sent to me. What does "EQP is 'Open'" mean? I did confirm outwards and return legs with them so it shouldn't mean "open ticket". What exactly does "EQP" refer to?

[image]

Comment: What airline was this?

Comment: @Michael It's KLM.

Comment: Elite Qualifying Points

Comment: @GayotFow Not elite qualifying points

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"EQP" stands for Equipment (or frequently "Equipment type"), and would normally describe the aircraft type being used for the flight (eg, Boeing 747, Airbus A380, etc).

"Open" could refer to the fact that the aircraft type hasn't yet been decided upon, although that is unlikely now days.  More likely, it's simply a field that hasn't passed over correctly from the airlines booking system to whatever system your travel agent is using. There are multiple different systems used by various airlines/travel agencies, and it's not uncommon to find fields like this that frequently aren't shown on a confirmation not being correctly populated as a result.

Comment: On the confirmation right after "Open" in the next line, "Boeing 747-400 Combi" is shown. I'm confused why the equipment is still undetermined despite an aircraft type has already been shown.

Comment: This basically confirms that EQP stands for Equipment, and the EQP is a 747-400 Combi. In that case, I'd put it down to fields not mapping correctly

Comment: As an aside, I wasn't aware anyone still flew the 744 Combi, but apparently KLM do! The front 2/3rds of the plane is passengers, the back 1/3 is freight!

Comment: KLM flies combi 747s on some of their Asia routes that I have traveled.